# Get back group of objects in Xcode 5 library

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is there any way to get back Object groups in library of Xcode 5 just like it was in Xcode 4. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think so. However, you can click the little grid/list button at the bottom left to show the library as a grid. If you can recognize the icons, and don’t need the text labels, it makes it much quicker to scroll through the list. (This does not work well for snippets, because they all have the same icon.)